# Plotting Pi using Monte Carlo Method

Tags: python

I can evaluate the  value of pi  using  different  data points  by Python. But for each repeat I want to plot the scatter  plot  like this: 
[image]

My python code for finding pi using monte carlo method is :

```
from random import *
from math import sqrt
inside=0
n=10**6
for i in range(0,n):
    x=random()
    y=random()
    if sqrt(x*x+y*y)<=1:
        inside+=1
pi=4*inside/n
print (pi)
```

Comment: Have a look at `matplotlib.pyplot`.

Comment: I have looked that and i can plot the very basic scatter  plot using  matplotlib.pyplot, but I'm confused how will i represent this.

Comment: minor (speedup) suggestion: there is no need for `sqrt`... `sqrt(x) <= 1` is the same condition as `x<=1` (for real `x`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

building from your code, this may get you started:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from random import random

inside = 0
n = 10**3

x_inside = []
y_inside = []
x_outside = []
y_outside = []

for _ in range(n):
    x = random()
    y = random()
    if x**2+y**2 <= 1:
        inside += 1
        x_inside.append(x)
        y_inside.append(y)
    else:
        x_outside.append(x)
        y_outside.append(y)

pi = 4*inside/n
print(pi)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_aspect('equal')
ax.scatter(x_inside, y_inside, color='g', marker='s')
ax.scatter(x_outside, y_outside, color='r', marker='s')
fig.show()
```

although i prefer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43703895/4954037) that uses numpy from the start...

Comment: I get the numerical value of pi using your code but not the  plot. it shows "matplotlib.collections.PathCollection at 0x11a73d278" . I don't understand  it.  I'm using Iphython

Comment: @css_wp forgot to add the `fig.show()`. sorry. i used [spyder](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder) for this... plots are displayed automatically inside the `ipython` shell within spyder.

Comment: i'm a  new  python user. I have tried your code again but it shows " UserWarning: matplotlib is currently using a non-GUI backend, so cannot show the figure
  "matplotlib is currently using a non-GUI backend, ""

Comment: or this: https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/3/notebook/notebook.html#plotting; did you run the `%matplotlib` magic command?

Answer (score 5):

If you get errors about the backend use this:

```
import matplotlib as mp
mp.use('Tkagg')
```

Which will set the backend to TkAgg, which uses the Tkinter user interface toolkit.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

n=1e3
x = 1-2*np.random.random(int(n))
y = 1-2.*np.random.random(int(n))
insideX,  insideY  = x[(x*x+y*y)<=1],y[(x*x+y*y)<=1]
outsideX, outsideY = x[(x*x+y*y)>1],y[(x*x+y*y)>1]

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1)
ax.scatter(insideX, insideY, c='b', alpha=0.8, edgecolor=None)
ax.scatter(outsideX, outsideY, c='r', alpha=0.8, edgecolor=None)
ax.set_aspect('equal')
fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: I use  ipython. Whenever I try to run your  code  it shows  "UserWarning: matplotlib is currently using a non-GUI backend, so cannot show the figure
  "matplotlib is currently using a non-GUI backend, ""

Comment: I'm using ipython 3. WHen i used 'import matplotlib as mp
mp.use('Tkagg')'
  it shows that "UserWarning:  This call to matplotlib.use() has no effect
because the backend has already been chosen;
matplotlib.use() must be called *before* pylab, matplotlib.pyplot,
or matplotlib.backends is imported for the first time.

  warnings.warn(_use_error_msg)"

Comment: Restart your ipython and try again

Answer (score 3):

To further elaborate Robbie's code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

n = 1000
xy = np.random.uniform(-1, 1, 2 * n).reshape((2, n))
in_marker = xy[0]**2 + xy[1]**2 <= 1
pi = np.sum(in_marker) / n * 4
in_xy = xy[:, in_marker]
out_xy = xy[:, ~in_marker]


fig, ax = plt.subplots(1)
ax.scatter(*in_xy,c='b')
ax.scatter(*out_xy,c='r')
ax.set_aspect('equal')
fig.show()
```

Comment: whoa! nice! how about this as condition `in_marker = np.hypot(*xy) <= 1`? ok, then the `sqrt` would be back.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a variation on hiro protagonist's code, using random.uniform() to allow for random numbers between -1.0 and 1.0, allowing all the points to be plotted, and not just 1/4 of it (not the most elegant code, but it is spelled-out to learn the basics of the Monte Carlo Simulation):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random

inside = 0
n = 10**3

x_inside = []
y_inside = []
x_outside = []
y_outside = []

for _ in range(n):
    x = random.uniform(-1.0,1.0)
    y = random.uniform(-1.0,1.0)
    if x**2+y**2 <= 1:
        inside += 1
        x_inside.append(x)
        y_inside.append(y)
    else:
        x_outside.append(x)
        y_outside.append(y)
```

To estimate pi, the points in the circle correspond to the area of the circle enclosing it (pi*radius^2) and the total points correspond to the area of the square enclosing it (2*radius)^2. So this translates into:

(points in the circle)/(total points) =  (pi*radius^2)/(2*radius)^2

Solving for pi, the equation becomes:

pi=4*(points in the circle)/(total points)

```
pi = 4*inside/n
print(pi)
```

Plot the points inside and outside the circle:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_aspect('equal')
ax.scatter(x_inside, y_inside, color='g', marker='s')
ax.scatter(x_outside, y_outside, color='r', marker='s')
fig.show()
```

[Plot of points inside and outside the circle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZHNwt.png)